# Request Facebook permissions without user leaving my website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get permission to access a Facebook user's User ID without having them leave your webpage?  Is an iframe with the permission dialog the only true way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Javascript API to Extend Permissions.
Lets say that you have already request the Email permission,
If you pass a new permission to the login button, the User must approve the new perm also.

**example Login Button:**

```
<fb:login-button perms="friend_likes"></fb:login-button>
```

**example FB.login()**

```
function fbAuth() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        alert('User fully authorize the app.');
      } else {
        alert('User canceled login or did not fully authorize the app.');
      }
    }, { scope: 'friend_likes' });
}
```

then you can call it with an onclick event or any other method you want:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return fbAuth();">Login</a>
```